# How to input a struct in a MIPS syscall?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, struct, mips

I want to create a basic server in Linux MIPS by doing this I need to use sockets and the syscalls provided by the kernel. Apart of the socket flow I need to call the functions bind, connect, accept etc. These sycalls (much like their C counterpart) take structs as their arguments, `struct sockaddr *umyaddr`. Only thing is I am not sure how to create these struct object and add them to `$a0` as an argument as structs aren't something native to mips. My mips architecture is Mips Linux o32 and the list of syscalls is here, https://syscalls.w3challs.com/?arch=mips_o32.

To my understanding using these sycalls is identical to using them in C and thats why I am trying to add arguments in my Mips code as if I were doing the same thing in C. To my understanding also Structs in C are compiled in a weird way with many optimization and not always a 1-1 byte block and the memory inside the struct is not always right beside each other in the stack and thats why I cant just replicate a struct in mips.

So what can I do here?

Comment: The syscalls expect **pointers** on structure. And the structures are just like array of bytes : no padding is required.

Comment: @Mathieu so I can just allocate the equivalent length of entries in the struct, say sizeof(sa_family_t) fill it with my sa_family, do the same for char sa_data[14];(14 bytes) then just move that first pointer when I began allocation ($sp - (sizeof(sa_family_t) + 14) into the argument slot? Also thank you for the response